# Show that pairwise uncorrelated Random Variables $X_1,X_2,...$ with $P(X_m = m)=\frac{1}{2}= P(X_m=-m)$ don't obey the weak law of large numbers.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of pairwise uncorrelated Random Variables with $P(X_m = m)=\frac{1}{2}= P(X_m=-m)$. I want to show that this sequence doesn't obey the weak law of large numbers. Here's what I've got so far:
Obviously, $E[X_m] =0, \hspace{2mm} \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$.
So what we need to show is that $\exists \hspace{1mm} \epsilon$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}(X_m) \right| \geq \epsilon \right) > 0$$ if I'm not mistaken. Now  intuitively what we need to show is that the sum of increasing (in absoulute value) integers with random signs doesn't zero out, i.e. the summands don't cancel in the long run. My guess is that I need to bound the expression $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}(X_m) \right| $  from below somehow and that that doesn't converge (in probability) to zero either, but I'm very unsure, as I'm rather new to rigorous probability proofs.

Comment: I'm given the hint, that wlln implies $\lim_n \to \infty P(|X_n/n|\geq\epsilon)= 0$, a condition obviously not staisfied by the sequence.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet I'm not sure why you think that any kind of CLT holds in this case, but I suggest you read the problem more carefully. The quantity $n^{-1}\sum_1^n X_m$ will have $O(1)$ fluctuations infinitely often.

Comment: @ghthorpe Take $S_n$ to be the partial sums. if $S_n/n$ tends to zero in probability, then so does $S_{n-1}/n$, and thus so does their difference.

Comment: Wow, I really misread this. Absolutely, with $X_m=\pm m,$ the story is quite different from $X_m=\pm 1,$ which was somehow what I had come away with after I read this. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1):

The weak law of large numbers states that $\frac{S_n}{n} \xrightarrow{P} 0$ in our case, where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. We want to contradict this.

Note that if this were true, then $P(\frac{S_n}{n} > \epsilon) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Now, of course, note that $\frac{n-1}{n} \xrightarrow{P} 1$(think of them as constant random variables) , so we get:  $$\frac{S_{n-1}}{n} = \frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n} \xrightarrow{P}0 \times 1 = 0$$

(As an exercise, if $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ in probability, then $X_nY_n \to XY$ in probabilty).

Hence, $\frac{X_n}{n} = \frac{S_{n}-S_{n-1}}{n} \xrightarrow{P} 0$. However, this is not true in our case, since $\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right| = 1$ for all $n$.

Hence, $X_n$ does not satisfy the weak law of large numbers.